# Preserve WALs on promoted node in PostgreSQL 14

Tags: postgresql, replication, transaction-log, postgresql-14

I have PostgreSQL streaming replication setup using replication slot. Node1 is primary and Node2 is slave. Now, node1 is down and promoted node2. Node2 is running and in read-write mode. There is heavy load on node2 now. How i can make sure enough WALs getting preserved on node2, so that when node1 joins, it could do diff sync using `pg_rewind`. This is PostgreSQL 14. There is no WAL archiving setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you'd have to create a replication slot on Node2 during failover:

```
SELECT pg_create_physical_replication_slot(
          slot_name => 'slot',
          immediately_reserve => TRUE
       );
```

Comment: If lets say i do not create slot, then how much WALs it will preserve? Is it `wal_keep_size` or `min_wal_size`?

Comment: `wal_keep_size`. `min_wal_size` is about WAL for the future, not old WAL.

Comment: Don't we need to preserve the newer WAL after the promotion on new primary so that pg_rewind works correctly?

Comment: Here, default value for min_wal_size is just 80MB and i have heavy workload on promoted primary. I want to preserve at least 1GB of newer workload or WAL on newer primary without creating slot. What should be values for wal_keep_size and min_wal_size in this case?

Comment: I'm not talking about *recent* WAL in the context of `min_wal_size`, I am talking about *future* WAL. Please read the documentation on `wal_keep_size`. That is the parameter that makes the primary retain *old* WAL. Replication slots are better.

Comment: I read doc and it creates confusion to me. My use case is simple for which i could not find any satisfactory answer yet. After promoting the node, i want to preserve 1GB of data for old primary. You can consider this as max lag by which old primary can remain shutdown. I want to achieve this without replication slot. Not able to find out what should be parameters values for this case

Comment: I'm not going to repeat myself. I already told you twice.